# What should I do if the reason a question should be closed changes?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

A question was recently closed as being unclear what was being asked.  The OP edited to make it clearer and I found it in the queue for potential reopenings.  I think it is now clear what the OP was asking, but I also think that the question should be closed as opinion based.

In cases where the close reason has changed, which of the following should I do?

1. Leave a comment to the OP explaining why the current phrasing is problematic and also flag a mod asking to update the reason for closure. (This is the option I chose for the question mentioned above, but I don't know if it's even possible for a mod to change the close reason).
2. Vote to re-open the question and then vote to close it again for a new reason if it gets re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option (well, *one* option) would be for another option in the 'leave closed' button, to choose the actual close reason again rather than just pressing 'leave closed' and leaving it at that.

This is beneficial in two ways;

1) It forces the reviewer to put a bit of thought into why they're leaving it closed.

2) It gives the reviewer an option to change the close reason (as you've requested in your question).

For reference; I've found a similar question on the main Meta.StackOverflow site about this very topic, so I've cross-posted this answer to there too, see if that draws a bit more attention to this situation.

Meta Stackoverflow: [Should provide the option for a new close reason when reviewing requests to re-open](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187860/should-provide-the-option-for-a-new-close-reason-when-reviewing-requests-to-re-o)

Comment: I had this exact problem earlier. This solution would make a lot of sense.

Comment: Depending on answers to my question, I was considering proposing this as a feature request; it's good to see it has already been proposed on the main Meta.SO. :)  Mainly, though, I'm wondering if there's any consensus as to what can be done for the time being, given that a change-close-reason button does not yet exist.